# How do I make an nginx proxy stop redirecting to root?

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy

I have a node app running as a proxy on nginx in a sub-directory. I'm having trouble with redirects that point to a different part of the app itself. They always redirect to the root instead of the proxy's sub-directory.

***Example:***

If my app proxy is at `https://example.com/myApp/` and it redirects to `/admin/` I want the page to redirect to `https://example.com/myApp/admin/` not `https://example.com/admin/`.

---

Here is the relevant section of my config:

```
  location /myApp {
    rewrite /myApp(.*) $1 break;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:3030/ /myApp/;
  }
```

I also tried setting `proxy_redirect` to `(^|^http://localhost:3030)/ /myApp/;`

---

Here is the full config file for this domain:

```
upstream php-handler {
  #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
  server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

## HTTP
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

## HTTPS
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/www.example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/www.example.com.key;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

  root /var/www/example.com/;
  index index.html index.php;

  client_max_body_size 500M;
  fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;
  gzip on;

  # Website
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }

  }

  # My App
  location /myApp {
    rewrite /myApp(.*) $1 break;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:3030;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:3030/ /myApp/;

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out on my own.

**tl;dr:**

This worked:

```
proxy_redirect ~(^http://localhost:3030|^)/(.*)$ /myApp/$2;
```

---

## First option:

```
proxy_redirect / /myApp/;
```

I'm guessing this works because the app is redirecting to `/admin/` not `http://localhost:3030/admin/`. This, however, does not provide the flexibility I'm looking for.

---

## Second Option:

### Use RegExp

So I made a couple mistakes originally when I tried using regex like this:

```
proxy_redirect (^|^http://localhost:3030)/ /myApp/;
```

**First**, if you're going to use regex you need to start it with `~` for case sensitive or `~*` for case insensitive.

**Secondly**, when you use regex it apparently replaces the full path instead of just the matched portion. For instance if you were to set a proxy_redirect like this:

```
proxy_redirect ~/(a|b)/ /myApp/;
```

If you then redirect to `/a/some-subdirectory/` the rewrite will result in `/myApp/` not `/myApp/some-subdirectory/`. To make this work you need to capture the end of the path and insert that onto the end of the rewrite like this:

```
proxy_rewrite ~/(a|b)/(.*)$ /myApp/$2;
```

***Note***: I can't find any information on this behavior in the docs. I am just basing this on the results of my own trial and error.

---

So my final proxy_redirect looks like this:

```
proxy_redirect ~(^http://localhost:3030|^)/(.*)$ /myApp/$2;
```

Answer (score -3):

From my point of view, you should try the listen directive in the server block define it as the default (source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html):

```
listen       80  

default_server;
```

The following declaration is meant as an invalid server name (source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) (so it never intersect any of your valid domain) :

```
Server_name _;
```

To fix you problem, make sure you have a server block with listen (port) and server_name (virtual host) - this one will be triggered first as you go from 'more precise to less precise' when you do virtual host names matching in nginx:

```
Listen 80 

Server_name your-domain-name.com;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to say. My location block is nested inside the domain's server block. Are you saying it shouldn't be? I'll add the rest of the domain's config to prevent any confusion.